# How to print nested Control Headings using Report Writer and GnuCOBOL?

Tags: report, cobol, gnucobol

I'm trying to create a report declared in the "report section" of a COBOL program. The program takes the `data.txt` file as input, and writes the report to the `report.txt` file. Here you can see the COBOL source code followed by the content of the input file:

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. PROGRAM.

      *
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
      *

       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT F-DATA
               ASSIGN TO 'data.txt'
               LINE SEQUENTIAL.
           SELECT F-REPORT
               ASSIGN TO 'report.txt'
               LINE SEQUENTIAL.

      *
       DATA DIVISION.
      *

       FILE SECTION.
       FD F-DATA.
       01 R-DATA.
           05 GRP       PIC A(01).
           05 NAME      PIC X(04).
           05 SCORE     PIC 9(02).
           05 FILLER    PIC X(72).
       FD F-REPORT
           REPORT IS REP.

       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       77 FS-DATA       PIC 9(02).
       77 FS-REPORT     PIC 9(02).
       77 EOF           PIC A(01).

       REPORT SECTION.
       RD REP
           PAGE LIMIT 10
           CONTROLS ARE GRP NAME.
       01 TYPE CH FOR GRP.
           02 LINE +1.
               03 COL  1 PIC A(05) VALUE 'GROUP'.
               03 COL +2 PIC A(01) SOURCE GRP.
       01 TYPE CH FOR NAME.
           02 LINE +1.
               03 COL  3 PIC X(16) SOURCE NAME.
       01 DET TYPE DE.
           02 LINE +1.
               03 COL  5 PIC 9(02) SOURCE SCORE.
       01 TYPE CF FOR NAME.
           02 LINE +1.
               03 COL  3 PIC A(05) VALUE 'TOTAL'.
               03 COL +2 PIC X(04) SOURCE NAME.
               03 COL +2 PIC X(01) VALUE '='.
               03 COL +2 PIC 9(02) SUM OF SCORE.
       01 TYPE CF FOR GRP.
           02 LINE +1.
               03 COL  1 PIC A(11) VALUE 'TOTAL GROUP'.
               03 COL +2 PIC A(01) SOURCE GRP.
               03 COL +2 PIC X(01) VALUE '='.
               03 COL +2 PIC 9(02) SUM OF SCORE.

      *
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
      *

       P-MAIN.
           MOVE 'N' TO EOF
           OPEN INPUT F-DATA
           OPEN OUTPUT F-REPORT
           INITIATE REP
           PERFORM P-READ
           PERFORM UNTIL EOF = 'Y'
               GENERATE DET
               PERFORM P-READ
           END-PERFORM
           TERMINATE REP
           CLOSE F-REPORT
           CLOSE F-DATA
           STOP RUN
           .

       P-READ.
           READ F-DATA
               AT END MOVE 'Y' TO EOF
           END-READ
           .
```

```
AJOHN01
AJOHN10
AJACK02
AJACK20
```

The program is compiled and executed with the following command:

```
cobc -xj program.cob
```

Here is the actual content of the output file:

```
  JOHN
GROUP A
    01
    10
  TOTAL JOHN = 11
  JACK
    02
    20
  TOTAL JACK = 22
TOTAL GROUP A = 33
```

And the content I expected:

```
GROUP A
  JOHN
    01
    10
  TOTAL JOHN = 11
  JACK
    02
    20
  TOTAL JACK = 22
TOTAL GROUP A = 33
```

Am I doing something wrong?

My version of GnuCOBOL is `4.0-early-dev.0`. This is the version you get when you install GnuCOBOL with apt, like so:

```
sudo apt install gnucobol
```